# Remove a duplicate row in table when being added from an array?

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```js
getELE("btnAddStudent").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ID = getELE("txtID").value;
    var Name = getELE("txtName").value;
    var Score = getELE("txtScore).value;

    var St = new Student(ID, Name, Score);
    List.Add(St);
```

```js
    var table = getELE("tbodyStudent"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < List.arrSt.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var key of ['ID', 'Name', 'Score']) 
        {
            var td = document.createElement("td");

            td.innerHTML = List.arrSt[i][key];
            tr.appendChild(td);

        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
});
```

The problem is whenever I add a new student, the table will add a **whole list of students** instead of **adding just the new student** to it making it have duplicate students.

How do I add just the new student instead of the whole list?

I have tried to tweak [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50995002/12310994) into my "for" loop but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems that you add whole list again to your table.

Here's updated code. Please try this.

```
getELE("btnAddStudent").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var ID = getELE("txtID").value;
    var Name = getELE("txtName").value;
    var Score = getELE("txtScore).value;

    var St = new Student(ID, Name, Score);
    var table = getELE("tbodyStudent"); 

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var key of ['ID', 'Name', 'Score']) 
    {
        var td = document.createElement("td");

        td.innerHTML = St[key];
        tr.appendChild(td);

    }
    table.appendChild(tr);

    List.Add(St);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is add the `tr` when you are adding a new student.

```
 var table = getELE("tbodyStudent"); 
 var tr = document.createElement("tr");
 for (var key of ['ID', 'Name', 'Score']) 
 {
     var td = document.createElement("td");

     // add here the new Student data
     td.innerHTML = newStudentData[key];

     tr.appendChild(td);
 }
 table.appendChild(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above solution.

It is a good solution Adding a row when you add a new student.